# PHP chained method, how to know which is the last one

Tags: php, oop, method-chaining, method-call

The situation:

```
Class MyClass {
    ...
    public function method($args) {
        // code
        ...
        if (is the last call) {
            return $something;
        }
        return $this;
    }
    ...
}
....
$obj = new MyClass;
$obj->method($some_args)->method($something_else)->method($more_data);
```

How can I know if the last call of `method` is actually the last?

Comment: I don't know.  You tell me.  What invokes this code?  Does $args inform us this is the last pass?  Otherwise your check probably needs to be performed where this is called from.

Comment: In general, functions should *not* be responsible for knowing that information. They should be self-contained bits of code that do exactly one thing well. There is probably an answer somewhere that will make you happy, but it will almost undoubtedly make your code worse.

Comment: Thankyou, well there is not a real scenario so $args and the rest of code  aren't important, it's only a very generic situation. I've think about it while coding a small framework for study

Answer (score 3):

When a function is called it is at that moment ALWAYS the last call to that function. PHP doesn't know if your script will actually do another function call after that one.

That being said you could probably bypass using the __destruct magic function, for example:

```
<?php

Class MyClass {
    private $method_queue = array();

    public function method($args) {
        array_push($this->method_queue, $args);
        return $this;
    }

    private function _method($args, $is_last) {
        // do actual stuff
        echo $args;

        if ($is_last) {
            echo "LAST";
            // do more stuff
        }
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        foreach ($this->method_queue as $k=>$args) {
            $this->_method($args, count($this->method_queue)-1==$k);
        }
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass;
$obj->method(1)->method(2)->method(3);
```

Comment: I hate that this is such a neat solution since using it smells like such a bad idea ;)

Comment: Well for sure the method names could be more descriptive, but that depends entirely on the usage scenario. I don't think using __destruct is a bad solution in itself and I have no idea what the context of his problem is..

Comment: Expecting a method to know the context in which it was called without passing something to define context is a bad practice from my point of view. I did not mean your example specifically was a bad idea, I mean the need for it indicates that the code could be built better.

Comment: Yeah on that I fully agree

Comment: Thank you, there isn't a real scenario, while coding a small framework for study I tried to think if a action like this it is possible, nothing more... and without considering if this practice is good or not, i like very much your idea :)